How can NotificationListenerService used in MAUI?
I'm trying to listen to notifications of other apps and for that purpose I tried to utilize NotificationListenerService.
I have seen several examples from Xamarin, but nothing seems to work.
So how is it done in MAUI? How is the NotificationListenerService accessed?
Here is my code from the AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />

    <service android:name=".NotificationListener"
    android:label="@string/NotificationListener"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</manifest>

And here you can see the file with the class that extends NotificationListenerService:
   using Android.Runtime;
   using Android.OS;
   using Android.Service.Notification;

    [Android.Runtime.Register("android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
    public class NLService : NotificationListenerService
        {
            public override void OnCreate()
            {
                base.OnCreate();
                Log.Info("start running", "Service Created");
            }
            public override void OnDestroy()
            {
                base.OnDestroy();
            }
            public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
            {
                return base.OnBind(intent);
            }
            public override bool OnUnbind(Intent intent)
            {
                return base.OnUnbind(intent);
            }
            public override void OnNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
            {
                base.OnNotificationPosted(sbn);
            }
    
            public override void OnNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn)
            {
                base.OnNotificationRemoved(sbn);
            }
        }


but nothing seems to work What have you tried?  Where exactly is it not working? Can you elaborate on your problem?

I have declared the service in AndroidManifest.xml as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.service.notification.notificationlistenerservice?view=net-android-34.0 in "Remarks" section.
I still get CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), so either I'm missing something else or there is a problem with MAUI...

How can we reproduce this problem, could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

I have added the code I try unsuccessfully to run. You can try to reproduce the problem.

I tried the code you shared, but I couldn't reproduce this problem on my side.  Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

That's all the changes I have made to the code to a new MAUI project. There are no other code modifications. I have created a new project in Visual Studio and I have added a file which contains only the NLService class + I have modified the AndroidManifest.xml as I have already shared in my post.

By the way, I'm using .NET 8 if that makes any difference.

You can use the following code to go to the Notification settings to check if the app has been granted by the permission. Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));

Well, the solution was to wrap the code in a preprocessor directive:
#if ANDROID

#endif

